# Acrobat Custom Command to edit multiple form field formats

Tags: pdf, javascript, adobe-acrobat, forms, acrobat-pro-dc

Due to the fact that when editing multiple forms fields in Acrobat DC you cant change the Format (eg. from none to number), is there a simple actionscript/Custom Command that could be set up to run in Acrobat that takes the currently selected form fields and changes their format from none to number, o decimal places, no separators, no symbols?

Otherwise you have to individually select each field, right-click Properties and set it each time.

Comment: It is possible to set Format field properties using JavaScript, run from the Console.

Comment: How would you write this to do the above?